# Is there an API limit to product rules on a Bigcommerce customer group?

Tags: bigcommerce

Does anyone know if there is a limit to the number of product rules that can be applied to a customer group using the API?

I am able to set 1474 before it starts to return a status 400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a hard limit on the number of rules a customer group can have, but it does start to act up once you get into that range.

If you can provide some context to what functionality you are looking to accomplish, I can try to provide a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to implement a surcharge for customers in a certain group. I worked round it by adding an additional tax class. Would be good if the limit was outlined in the API documentation.